# Navbar items change color depending on their current position

Tags: colors, scroll, navbar

I would like to do the same thing with my navbar for my school website project - check this page out as reference - http://www.sketchin.ch/ when you scroll, the hole navbar changes its color.

is this canvas used? Please, I really, really need help with this! Any ideas will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Basically, there are two different menus. The video header at the top is a higher z-index than the black menu. As you scroll down, this menu then comes into view.

Both menus are the same fixed position as each other. The white menu is inside of that first section, which has overflow set to hidden. This means that as you scroll down, the white menu is fixed and so goes out of the header section, so it becomes hidden, and the other menu appears from below the first section because it too is fixed position..